# refresh frequenlty a div via jquery .load function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to refresh a `div` every minute via jquery `.load()` function. I have writen the code below:

```
function fn60sec() {
     // runs every 60 sec and runs on init.
     var pathname = window.location.pathname;
     $( "#user-card" ).load( pathname + " #user-card" );
}
fn60sec();
setInterval(fn60sec, 60*1000);
```

However the code above doesn't work. What is wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `$( "#user-card" ).load( pathname + "/#user-card" );`

Comment: try $( "#user-card" ).html( pathname + " #user-card" );